# How to understand below Groovy script function?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am not familiar with SOAP-Groovy script and I am trying to use below function for one of my SOAP test in my project. Though it works fine (returning my test-case properties), but I am not able to understand its flow/structure.

What is `keySet().inject([:]){map, key ->  map[key]...` ? What we are actually mapping here?

In assert:

```
assert properties instanceof Properties
```

`instanceof Properties` stands for what?

I need to understand below function flow and structure:

```
def writeTestCasePropertiesToFile = {
    //Get the test case properties as Properties object
    def properties =  context.testCase.properties.keySet().inject([:]){map, key ->  map[key] = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(key); map as Properties}  
    log.info properties
    assert properties instanceof Properties
    properties?.store(new File(propFileName).newWriter(), null) 
}
```

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you write more details, what you want to understand?

Comment: please edit your post and try to tell us about your problem. I think it just a `function`

Comment: I have updated my Post. I need help to understand that function flow. As i am not familiar with groovy... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function gets properties from the current testcase.
They are normally returned as a Map instance. But here they are converted into an instance of Properties.
After asserting that this is indeed an instance of Properties, they are saved to a new file. The name is set in the propFileName, which I assume must be a global variable set outside this function.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Steen. Yes propFileName is defined as variable outside this function.